# Usage of "got" as "to have" in an informal American English sentence

Tags: informal-language

Is it correct to use this kind of ebonics structure?:

John: I have some tickets here for the tonight film that you want to watch.

Jennifer: How many do you got?

Is it o.k to replace the verb "got" instead of "have" here like in the possessive structure "have got"?

Comment: FYI -- I recommend you avoid the term *Ebonics*. It was coined in the 1970s to designate a hypothetical continuity of linguistic phenomena from West Africa through the Caribbean to the US, but even those who endorsed the theory preferred to call the speech of African-Americans *Black English*. The term became known to the general public in the 1990s primarily as a label for a politically controversial approach to teaching English to African-American students. Linguists have never to my knowledge used the term; the usual name for the dialect today is AAVE--African-American Vernacular English.

Comment: Have got and have mean the same thing. But *have* in "have got" is normally omitted in spoken English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gut check, from a native speaker of American English but *not* a native speaker of Ebonics: Yes, you can, but it sounds less idiomatic than "How many you got?", without the "do". (And the "you" would be pronounced "ya".)